# How to get the html of a div from a different page with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I get the html of a certain html element which is located on a different site?

Solution:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'somefile.html',
success: function(data) {
    data=$(data).find('div#id');
    $('#mydiv').html(data);
    alert('Done.');
 }
});
```

Comment: By "another page", do you mean one of your own pages?  Or a page from a completely different website?

Comment: very unlikely...unless it's the same webapp/site this might be impossible for obvious security reasons

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: by 'another page' I mean a page on the same domain, but with another path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a ajax call to a php or any other file , use CURL or other tools to grab the page you want and extract the div and echo it and then when you get back the html just put it inside a div in your page

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'somefile.html',
    success: function(data) {
                    data=$(data).find('div#id');
        $('#mydiv').html(data);
        alert('Done.');
     }
    });
```

Comment: Why use such long code when it can be done by single line code in jQuery

Comment: just letting him know all his options. learning curl is certainly helpful in many cases.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [$.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) with an appended container

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

```
$('#div_id_in_your_page').load('ajax_page.html #required_div');
```

For class:

```
$('.div_class_in_your_page').load('ajax_page.html #required_div');
```

Comment: You need a space in your url string for the selector.

Comment: @Mathletics. You can easily fix it for him.

Comment: This one works. Is there any possibility to select a div by class name or just by ID? Can I use normal jQuery selectors?

Comment: @Sand_Spirit In  the left part you can use normal selectors. Check out the answer. Updated it

Comment: Actually, now I have realized it doesn't work. It just hides my div without loading the other one. What should I do?

Comment: @Sand_Spirit It should work, check this part of the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments  Be sure that the html div id which you specify is a valid one & exists

Comment: Perhaps there is a problem with my url? It doesn't have an extension.

Comment: could you be a bit more clear? like if no extension u must be using a cms or mvc. & speficy all these things clearly in your question

Comment: It isn't my site. I'm making a user script for it, so I need to load that div from another page. All url's do not contain any extension, they are just like this: www.thatsite.com/profile/Sand_Spirit/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12513/discussion-between-sand-spirit-and-gopi1410)

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

- send an ajax call to a server side script
- this script fetches the remote page and returns HTML as a response. (generally JSON is preferred)
- your page finally gets access to the html.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use like this.

```
$.ajax({
   url:"page2.html",
   success:function(response){
      $("#currentDIV").html(response);
   },error:function(){
      alert("error");
   }
});
```