# AJAX load external page div into current page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to load a div from another page using AJAX but it seems to load the entire page into my div. I would like to just load a specific div.

```
$('.overlay').on('click', function() {
    var page_url = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        url: page_url + ' #single_portfolio',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#overlay').html(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Does the page you are loading have more than the desired div within it?

Comment: Try using `.load()` instead: `$('#overlay').load(page_url + ' #single_portfolio');`

Comment: You can't do stuff like `' #single_portfolio'` with $.ajax, that's a syntax that only works with `.load`

Comment: Alex, `.load()` works fine. But I am trying to use `$.ajax` because I would like to show a loading bar before the html loads from the external page.

Comment: If not you can try something like this `var the_desired_div = $(data).find("#the_desired_div");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023051/how-to-get-the-html-of-a-div-from-a-different-page-with-ajax

Comment: @Shivam you can do that with .load

Comment: @Shivam see my answer. It shows how to use `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UvrqL/4/)</kbd>

You can do that with `.load()`:

```
$('#overlay').load(page_url + ' #single_portfolio');
```

If you must use `$.ajax()` try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: page_url,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#overlay').html($(data).children('#single_portfolio'));
        //or $(data).filter('#single_portfolio')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. `$(data).children` isn't working for me but `$(data).filter` does work.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a CSS selector in a remote document via AJAX like you're trying. The `#single_portfolio` after the URL would act as a `hash` (w/o the space in front). You need a URL that returns exactly what you need for your AJAX call. Alternatively, you can fetch the entire page, and do some processing in the callback function to extract the desired part.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you're trying to substitute the `$.ajax` call for the `$.load` call. Only `$.load` has the ability to load fragments of pages. From the `$.load` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of
>   the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special
>   syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of the string following the first
>   space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content
>   to be loaded.

```
$('#overlay').html(strLoadingBar).load(page_url + ' #single_portfolio');
// assuming you have your loading bar assigned to a string variable "strLoadingBar"
```

> When this method executes, it retrieves the content of ajax/test.html,
>   but then jQuery parses the returned document to find the element with
>   an ID of container. This element, along with its contents, is inserted
>   into the element with an ID of result, and the rest of the retrieved
>   document is discarded.
>
> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved
>   document and insert it into the current document. During this process,
>   browsers often filter elements from the document such as ,
>   , or  elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by
>   .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved
>   directly by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#overlay').load(page_url + ' #container');` instead of your `$.ajax()` call

See http://api.jquery.com/load/