# Uncaught SyntaxError - Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Whenever I do the following **ajax request** to get the html of a page:

```
      $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType:"jsonp",
            url: link,
            success: function(response){console.log(response)},
            async:true //asynchronous request
       });
```

I get the error:  `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"`

Why is this and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is "the html of a page" in `jsonp` format?

Comment: not sure. I'm sorta new to jsonp format requests. Is there any way to change it to jsonp format in my request? If not, how else could I get the html of the page without encountering an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error?

Comment: The server you are calling is not returning JSONP. You can not just set JSONP and expect it to work, the page you are calling needs to support it.

Comment: how can i know the datatype that it returns?

Comment: You can always try catch and handle it but find out why its happening.

Comment: Look at the request in the network tab and see what it is returning.

Comment: text/html?                                                                                          HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 02 Oct 2015 14:42:22 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: X-Forwarded-Proto,Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Wed, 30 Sep 2015 08:54:19 GMT
ETag: "701-520f313786a54-gzip"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: -1
P3P: CP="NON"
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 773
Keep-Alive: timeout=8, max=63
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: **If you have no control of the target server, you can't fix this problem without server-side code.**

Answer (score 0):

In the `dataType` attribute you're telling the function to expect a JSON response:

```
dataType:"jsonp"
```

The error you're getting is the error that occurs when your function expects JSON but instead gets HTML. Thus `Unexpected token <` is what is described by the error as the function fails to parse the HTML response (which unlike JSON usually starts with the '<' character).

Comment: I see. if I put html I get the following error and I'm not too sure about how I  would solve it: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Right, so either you have to follow the same origin policy, or you have to use proper jsonp. If you don't control the target server, you can't fix either of those problems with cilent-side javascript.

Comment: @jgozal Read what Kevin B said and also check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20035319/1200185).

Comment: I tried using CORS as well and it yielded the same error. Could it be that the server doesn't handle CORS requests? I am also trying another workaround. Say I load this page through an iFrame. Could I just get the html of the page like this?: $("#iFrame").contents().find("html").html()

Comment: @jgozal Maybe you should open a new question and ask about what you want to do specifically. Your issue is no longer related to this question.

Comment: it is very related. I am trying to get the html of an external page as explained in the first sentence of my question. If anybody can find another way to do it better than through an ajax request, that works too

Comment: @jgozal The title of this question refers to a JavaScript error, which doesn't really capture the bigger picture of what you're attempting to do.. Getting the HTML of a different-domain page solely through JavaScript is not going to work. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023051/how-to-get-the-html-of-a-div-from-a-different-page-with-ajax) approach.