# Checking a condition through Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have following code in jquery for my webpage http://localhost/currentpage

```
$('body').on('click', '.checkid', function(e) {
var url = 'http://localhost/newpage';
var id  =  $(this).attr('data-id');

   $.ajax({
   type: 'GET', 
   url: url,    
   success: function (data) {  }  
   }); 

 });
```

What I want need to do is I need to check whether there is an ID exists with same name in page http://localhost/newpage .Suppose the ID is myId , I need to check whether there is a ID with same name in http://localhost/newpage.

Can anybody help me how to execute it in jquery through ajax request for the above coding ?

Comment: So what is your issue? Send the data to the server and do the check.

Comment: I have updated the question, can someone help how can we achieve it through above jquery script

Comment: As the code is now, have you checked to see if you are getting anything back in the 'data' variable in your 'success' function? If so, are you getting what you expect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023051/how-to-get-the-html-of-a-div-from-a-different-page-with-ajax

Comment: I need help how check it inside the success function, tried but not working

Comment: again negation..sorry I don't aware about the negative impact made this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `data` in the AJAX response is a HTML string, you could check for the presence of your ID checking with a RegExp on the tags:

```
if (data.match(/<.*id="myId".*\/?>/gi)) {
  // a tag with ID "myId" has been found
}
```

The above code needs to be executed inside your `function success(data) {}` callback.

You can also achieve the same using jQuery, by doing `$(data).find('#myId').length > 0`

Comment: Thanks it worked as per this logic, but it is not the complete coding required in my custom syntax. I have corrected it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(data).find('#myId')`